# Connecting a NAS storage with 2 different VLAN/Router

Tags: routing, vlan, network

[image: Network Diagram]My query is we employee 2 routers 1 with ip `192.168.1.1` and other with `192.168.2.1` both have different type users connected to the them. Now the problem is i have a Network storage device which i want to share between both the router users. I don't know how to achieve it currently my network storage is connected to `192.168.1.1` router with static ip `192.168.1.18`. Is there a way that i can share the same network storage device with both router users?

Update : Both routers are Cisco RV042

NAS is single port WD Mycloud Mirror

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about hosts or servers are off-topic here. If you explain how the routers are connected and what the router models and configurations are, we may be able to to help with the configurations of them. After all, routers route packets from one network to another.

Comment: updated router info and you can see in the diagram how they are connected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use VLANs of the routers to make a new network for the server.  There are any number of ways of numbering your VLANs, this is just one.

If you have an extra switch you can do this.

- R1 gets a second IP address 192.168.9.1
- R2 gets 192.168.9.2
- NAS becomes 192.168.9.18, default route to 192.168.9.1

  ```
  ISP1                         ISP2
   |                            |
  R1          SW               R2
  ==========   ==========     ==========
  1  1  1  9   |    |   |     9  2  2  2
  |  |  |  |   |    |   |     |  |  |  |
  pc pc pc +---+   nas  +-----+  pc pc pc
  ```

Without another switch, you have to do something like this:

```
    ISP1                         ISP2
     |                            |
    R1                           R2
   ==========                  ==========
   1  1  9  9                  9  2  2  2
   |  |  |  |                  |  |  |  |
   pc pc |  +------------------+  pc pc pc
         nas
```

As the nas is now on the far side of a router (from the PCs) you may have to pay attention to how the PCs find it.  (DNS or IP address or whatever.)

Hope that's helpful

Comment: Genius! I think this might work. Will try soon

Answer (score 1):

There are three basic solutions:

1. physical connection - one interface on the NAS is directly connected to each router's network
2. virtual connection - the NAS is connected to each router's network by VLAN trunk; the VLANs are trunked together on an appropriate, shared switch or router; the VLAN trunk allows use of a single interface or multiple, aggregated interfaces (best solution imho)
3. routed connection - the routers are connected to each other, appropriate routes to the NAS and back are added to them, and they are configured to allow connections to the NAS for the remote network

edit:

- Apparently, the WD Mycloud Mirror doesn't support VLAN, so 2. is out.
- Your chart shows two connections to the router but the manual only
  shows one - 1. is out, too.
- What's your problem with 3.? Going through the RV042s will limit the access speed for the remote users to (at most) 100 Mbit/s; for faster speed I'd recommend a L3 switch.

Comment: regarding the first solution. If i connect NAS to both network it will indirectly connect my both the routers. And the client computer configured with each router will messing up with getting ip from DHCP. for eg. computer A perviously connected to router 1 might get ip from router 2 or vice versa

Comment: 2nd & 3rd solution i didn't get it wholly

Comment: Which solutions are possible depends on the models of your routers and what interfaces and software they have; also whether your NAS has multiple ethernet interfaces and its capabilities.  Without details, you'll only get general principles.

Comment: i updated my question kindly check and suggest

Comment: "If i connect NAS to both network it will indirectly connect my both the routers." - only when the NAS is configured to bridge or route between its interface; with the (assumed) default, there are just two connections.